# Create a truth table with multiple expressions

Tags: php, truthtable

I am a student at a university. Now, I am doing my excercise.

I my excercise, I must create a truth table (for digital board) with 42 variables (in 5 expressions). I can not do it, because it is a big truth table.

I tried to use this (http://turner.faculty.swau.edu/mathematics/materialslibrary/truth/), but I failed. Because, it supports for one expression only.

Do you have a better truth table generator? Let me know, thanks?

Comment: 42 variables is 4 trillion rows...

Answer (score -2):

I think CKen (http://cken.sourceforge.net/) (is good for you - @Dai Hung Le ).

CKen supports both ''upper cases'' and ''lower cases'', so it supports 58 (= 2x29) single variables!

And the most important, multi-expressions can be used in it (by separators):

Example: `a,b,c,d,e;(a+b)*c;d*e#a;`

On the other hand, it is very fast!

---

**You must define your variables before using it (variables) in your expressions.**